# Vaadin application throws exception upon deployment

Tags: deployment, tomcat9, vaadin23

I am still struggling to make Vaadin application work on Tomcat.
After taking care of one problem described in

[Vaadin application deployed to tomcat can't start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75578074/vaadin-application-deployed-to-tomcat-cant-start)
I am getting another exception that has no relation to my code.
I do not have any DataSources defined in my code. All the data I am getting through the REST API calls. Nevertheless, Tomcat won't run my war file and the following exception appears in the catalina.out file:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child       at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:686)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:662)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1023)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1910)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:123)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:824)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:474)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1617)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:318)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:898)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:795)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:871)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:249)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:428)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:917)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)       at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:347)       at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:478)    Caused
> by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
> [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/encyclopediaView]]
> at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)
> ... 35 more     Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]:
> Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method
> 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException:
> Failed to determine a suitable driver class       at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:175)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:155)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:97)
> at
> org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:174)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4929)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
> ... 36 more     Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method
> 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException:
> Failed to determine a suitable driver class       at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
> ... 58 more     Caused by:
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException:
> Failed to determine a suitable driver class       at
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.determineDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:182)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder(DataSourceProperties.java:123)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration.createDataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:48)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.dataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:64)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)       at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
> ... 59 more

As there is no mentioning of any of my classes, I do not know even where to look for problem.
When I was running this application as a JAR file from IDE I didn't have this problem and everything was working. I even added MySQL JDBC driver to the Tomcat /lib directory, but it didn't change a thing.

Can someone please tell me what else I can do to make it working on Tomcat?

Comment: Did you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31199853/3608089

Comment: Looking at the source code for `DataSourceProperties.determineDriverClassName()` it seems like that it is not possible to determine the driver based on the configured jdbc url, more than a missing jar issue.
How do you configure the jdbc url in your application?
If you do not specify anything, Spring Boot tries to set up an embedded db if any is present on classpath.
But perhaps you need to configure the datasource in the application properties file
Take a look here, for example: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/integrations/databases/mysql

Comment: I followed ollitietavainen advice and edited @SpringBootApplication annotation adding (exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class}).
The exception is gone now and application is deployed and running on the Tomcat. That problem is solved, but my application still isn't working. I created another question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75689080/vaadin-application-isnt-working-on-the-tomcat
Please take a look.

Comment: Could you formulate the above as an answer, so that this question is not left in un-answered state.