# Vaadin application isn't working on the Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, vaadin23

I finally was able to deploy my Vaadin application to the Tomcat 9 without any errors.
The Tomcat status shows status as running and log has no errors. The tail of it looks like this:

> 2023-03-08 21:35:22.487  INFO 64412 --- [alina-utility-2]
> o.g.e.EncyclopediaApplication            : Started
> EncyclopediaApplication in 9.009 seconds (JVM running for 2059.387)
> 2023-03-08 21:35:22.517  INFO 64412 --- [alina-utility-2]
> c.v.flow.server.startup.ServletDeployer  : Skipping automatic servlet
> registration because there is already a Vaadin servlet with the name
> springServlet 2023-03-08 21:35:22.517  WARN 64412 ---
> [alina-utility-2] c.v.f.s.c.JSR356WebsocketInitializer     :
> Atmosphere already initialized 2023-03-08 21:35:22.575  INFO 64412 ---
> [alina-utility-2] c.v.f.s.VaadinServletContextInitializer  : Search
> for VaadinAppShell took 57 ms 2023-03-08 21:35:22.708  INFO 64412 ---
> [alina-utility-2] c.v.f.s.DefaultDeploymentConfiguration   : Vaadin is
> running in production mode.
>
> The following EXPERIMENTAL features are enabled:
>
> - Use Webpack for front-end builds (Deprecated)

Nevertheless, I can't see my web page.
I have in my main view

```
@Route(value = "")
@PreserveOnRefresh
public class EncyclopediaMainLayout extends VerticalLayout {
```

but I can't see my web page in the browser. I see only this:
[image]

I did try to change the @Route value and redeploy my app. In this case I am getting 404 code.
So, what is going on? Where is my application? Please help

Comment: Can you please provide some technical details. How did you deploy vaadin? Did you put the war file in the webapps directory of tomcat? Or created a directory in tomcat's webspps dir? What is the name of the war-archive or directory?

Comment: I dropped my war file into the tomcat's  webapps directory. It was unpacked by the tomcat and directory with the name of my war file was created..

Comment: Try: http://localhost:8080/directory_with_the_name_of_war/

Comment: Thank you, It is working now. Put your comment as answer, so I can mark it as completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deploying a web applications in Tomcat is done by copying the application's war-archive to the `webapps` directory of tomcat or copying the directory containing the application to the `webapps` directory of tomcat.

Let's say the directory with your application is called `vaadin`. Or maybe you have an archive named `vaadin.war`. In both cases Tomcat deploys the application to the following address:

```
http://hostname:port/vaadin
```

In this example, `/vaadin` is called the context path in tomcat terminology.

See more information [in tomcat manual](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html)

On how to change the default behavior see the following [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276989/how-to-set-the-context-path-of-a-web-application-in-tomcat-7-0)